# How to retrieve max date for To_Date parameter

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have one `To_date` parameter in my report, and I have to pass max date vale into the `To_Date` parameter from two data sets, which contains date. How can I write expression to retrieve max date?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use below expression

```
  =IIF(MAX(Fields!PaymentDate.Value, "dsMain") > MAX(Fields!OrderCreatedDate.Value, "dsMain") 
, MAX(Fields!PaymentDate.Value, "dsMain") , MAX(Fields!OrderCreatedDate.Value, "dsMain"))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. i will try your given expression